# How do I index JSON format files using Elasticsearch in Python?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, indexing

Quite new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to read in `.json` file and trying to index the file. So far I have this but I am kind of unsure on how to proceed from here:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import json, sys

es = Elasticsearch()

def load(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as open_file:
            yield json.load(open_file)

helpers.bulk(es, load(sys.argv[1]), index='my-index', doc_type='my-type')
```

When I run this, I get error: `helpers.bulk(es, load_json(sys.argv[1]), index='my-index', doc_type='my-type')
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: method name is `load_json' or `load` . You have 2 different in the question

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see with is the arguments you are passing to the python code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand. Do you mean `sys.argv[1]` argument I am passing in load?